# Multi query format in C# (Not using C# SDK)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to figure out how to format a multiquery query string in C# but I can't use C# SDK.  So far this is what I have tried.

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/method/fql?q={'q1':'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE 'MyPage' in name)','q2':'select page_id, name, page_url, pic_small, pic_big from page where page_id in (SELECT page_id FROM #q1)','q3':'SELECT uid, name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND (uid2 IN (SELECT uid FROM #q1)))'}&access_token=myaccesstoken&format=json"
```

and

```
string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?queries={'q1':'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE 'MyPage' in name)','q2':'select page_id, name, page_url, pic_small, pic_big from page where page_id in (SELECT page_id FROM #q1)','q3':'SELECT uid, name, pic_small FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND (uid2 IN (SELECT uid FROM #q1)))'}&access_token=myaccesstoken&format=json"
```

Neither of them is working.  Can someone please help?

```
WebClient clientUser = new WebClient();
string JsonResult = clientUser.DownloadString(url);
JObject jsonUserInfo = null;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(JsonResult)) jsonUserInfo = JObject.Parse(JsonResult);
```

Comment: I should also mention that trying this graph api explorer give me Parser error: unexpected end of query."

Comment: How does the handler of the query know when single quotes begins and end ie for the select and then the string literal? Sure you don't need to escape the single quotes wrapping mypage?

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have access to the Uri type? That is your best bet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your single quotes eg wrapping the MyPage string literal.

Comment: It was totally because of a misplaced single '.